# Making random initial position by Python

Tags: python, numpy, random, position

I am now working to make rotational trajectories. In the beginning I need to define the initial position of an rotating object. How to make 1000 random initial position in three dimensions of this kind of object by Python or NumPy? I think a python function can solve the problem.

Comment: Use the `random` module. If you want a more detailed answer you will have to ask a more detailed question.

Comment: To start, take a look at the `numpy.random` module: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html  If you're not sure how to use any of those, take a look at their docstrings--many include examples in the docstrings.  If that doesn't help, edit your question with more information, including what you tried and what didn't work as you expected.  Also, you say "position", but you don't say how many dimensions.  Are you working with 2-D or 3-D positions?

Comment: I am working with 3-D positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, you need to pick up point uniformly distributed on a sphere. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) for details.

```
import math
import numpy as np

cos_theta = 2.0 * np.random.random(100) - 1.0
phi       = 2.0 * math.pi * np.random.random(100)

sin_theta = np.sqrt( (1.0 - cos_theta)*(1.0 + cos_theta) )

x = sin_theta * np.cos(phi)
y = sin_theta * np.sin(phi)
z = cos_theta

print(x, y, z)
print("---------------------")
print(np.square(x) + np.square(y) + np.square(z))
```